# Problemas con traduccion de plugin en wodpress, no funciona la traduccion con archivos .po y .mo

Tags: wordpress

Necesito realizar un plugin en wordpress que sea multilenguaje y la verdad que he investigado y al parecer la mejor manera es con archivos po y mo, pero ya realice las configuraciones e igualmente, no carga las traducciones. el plugin originalmente esta en 'en_US' y lo quiero cambiar a 'es_ES' o solo 'es' si cambio el idioma de wordpress

aca mi codigo

#### DiBi-Bot/languages/DiBi-Bot-es.po (tengo un clon de este mismo pero con es-ES, por si acaso)

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: DiBi-Bot\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-08-03 15:59-0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2018-08-03 15:59-0400\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: dibibot.com\n"
"Language: es\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.1.1\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: __;_e;_n\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: dibi-bot.php:56
msgid "DibiBot User"
msgstr "Usuario de DibiBot"

#: dibi-bot.php:57
msgid "DibiBot Operator"
msgstr "Operador de DibiBot"
```

#### DiBi-Bot/dibi-bot.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @link              https://localhost/
 * @since             1.0.0
 * @package           DiBi-Bot
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       DiBi-Bot
 * Plugin URI:        http://localhost
 * Description:       Chatbot de soporte a Clientes
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            Anthony Medina
 * Author URI:        https://localhost/
 * License:           Copyright 2019
 * License URI:       
 * Text Domain:       dibibot-plugin
 * Domain Path:       /languages/
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

define('DIBIBOT_PLUGIN_PATH' , plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)                           );


// funcion de wordpress para cargar el text domain
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'dibibot_load_textdomain');
function dibibot_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'DiBi-Bot', DIBIBOT_PLUGIN_PATH . 'languages/' );
}

// Quiero agregar estos roles de wordpress en ingles o espanol dependiendo del idioma de wordpress
function dibibot_add_roles() {
    $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
    add_role( 'dibibot_user', __('DibiBot User', 'DiBi-Bot'), $subscriber->capabilities );
    add_role( 'dibibot_operator', __('DibiBot Operator', 'DiBi-Bot'), $subscriber->capabilities );
}

// Activation and deactivaticion
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'dibibot_add_roles' );

?>
```

tengan en cuenta que el codigo lo simplifique, es decir le quite partes para que pudieran entender pero basicamente, las lineas donde hago uso de la traduccion en la funcion ´dibibot_add_roles corresponden tal cual con el que tengo en el archivo PO

Comment: El nombre del archivo no debería ser `es-ES.(po|mo)`, sino `es_ES.(po|mo)`, con el guión bajo `_` en lugar del medio `-`. Y el `domain` pasado como primer argumento de `load_plugin_textdomain` debe ser el mismo que el que especificas en los comentarios `dibibot-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el path podría estar incorrecto. Prueba esto…

```
function dibibot_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'DiBi-Bot', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}
```